# Explain output of cat /proc/vmallocinfo

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, proc

What does this output represent after doing `cat /proc/vmallocinfo`. I know, this gives mapping of virtual address space of kernel. But want to have in-depth understanding.

#### Questions

- What are actual allocation done by `vmalloc()`?
- Why multiple times allocations are seen from `n_tty_open`?
- Why there are gaps between two allocations like:

  - > 0xffffc90004000000-**0xffffc90005001000** 16781312 pci_iomap_range+0x66/0x80 phys=e0000000 ioremap
  - > **0xffffe8ffffc00000**-0xffffe8ffffe00000 2097152 pcpu_get_vm_areas+0x0/0x570 vmalloc

and any other resource which will clarify my doubt:

```
0xffffc90000000000-0xffffc90000004000   16384 acpi_os_map_iomem+0xf6/0x154 phys=bfff0000 ioremap
0xffffc90000004000-0xffffc90000405000 4198400 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=1024 vmalloc vpages N0=1024
0xffffc90000405000-0xffffc90000408000   12288 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=2 vmalloc N0=2
0xffffc90000408000-0xffffc90000609000 2101248 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=512 vmalloc N0=512
0xffffc90000609000-0xffffc9000061a000   69632 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=16 vmalloc N0=16
0xffffc9000061a000-0xffffc9000062b000   69632 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=16 vmalloc N0=16
0xffffc9000062b000-0xffffc9000062d000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc9000062d000-0xffffc9000066e000  266240 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=64 vmalloc N0=64
0xffffc9000066e000-0xffffc900006ef000  528384 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=128 vmalloc N0=128
0xffffc900006ef000-0xffffc90000700000   69632 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=16 vmalloc N0=16
0xffffc90000700000-0xffffc90000711000   69632 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=16 vmalloc N0=16
0xffffc90000711000-0xffffc90000716000   20480 alloc_large_system_hash+0x17a/0x238 pages=4 vmalloc N0=4
0xffffc90000716000-0xffffc90000718000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000718000-0xffffc9000071b000   12288 zs_cpu_notifier+0x49/0x90 ioremap
0xffffc9000071b000-0xffffc9000071d000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc9000071d000-0xffffc9000071f000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc9000071f000-0xffffc90000721000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000721000-0xffffc90000723000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000723000-0xffffc90000725000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000725000-0xffffc90000727000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000727000-0xffffc90000729000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc9000072b000-0xffffc9000072f000   16384 n_tty_open+0x19/0xe0 pages=3 vmalloc N0=3
0xffffc90000730000-0xffffc90000733000   12288 pci_iomap_range+0x66/0x80 phys=f0806000 ioremap
0xffffc90000733000-0xffffc90000737000   16384 n_tty_open+0x19/0xe0 pages=3 vmalloc N0=3
0xffffc90000737000-0xffffc9000073b000   16384 n_tty_open+0x19/0xe0 pages=3 vmalloc N0=3
0xffffc9000073b000-0xffffc9000073f000   16384 n_tty_open+0x19/0xe0 pages=3 vmalloc N0=3
0xffffc9000073f000-0xffffc90000741000    8192 bpf_prog_alloc+0x36/0xa0 pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000741000-0xffffc90000745000   16384 e1000_setup_all_tx_resources+0x97/0x550 [e1000] pages=3 vmalloc N0=3
0xffffc90000745000-0xffffc90000747000    8192 e1000_setup_all_rx_resources+0xa6/0x560 [e1000] pages=1 vmalloc N0=1
0xffffc90000747000-0xffffc9000074b000   16384 n_tty_open+0x19/0xe0 pages=3 vmalloc N0=3
```

Comment: Reference - https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt.

Answer (score 1):

- [vmalloc()](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-vmalloc.html) will allocate non-contiguous physical pages and mapping them to a contiguous virtual address region. These vmalloc virtual address are limited in vmalloc area of kernel space. (While in x86_64 platform is start from `0xffffc90000000000UL` as you show the infomation)
- Because the `n_tty_open` function use vmalloc to allocate for `struct n_tty_data`. You can check this in kernel source code.
- Each vmalloc region use one page gap to protect against overruns.